# Salvar valor em variável

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, sortable

Estou utilizando o [jQueryUI - Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/) para alterar as posições dos dados em uma tabela. Porém, eu preciso salvar a **posição inicial** (a posição que a linha estava antes de arrastar) e a **posição final** (para onde a linha foi arrastada).
Essas variáveis, eu utilizarei como parâmetro para chamar uma consulta `ajax`.

Minha tabela está da seguinte forma:

```
<h1>Classificar tabela utilizando jQuery UI</h1>
<a href='http://www.jqueryui.com/sortable/'>MjQuery UI - Sortable</a>

<table id="sort" class="grid">
    <thead>
        <tr><th class="index">Nº</th><th>Ano</th><th>Título</th><th>Tipo Sanguíneo</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td class="index">1</td><td>1969</td><td>Fulano de Tal</td><td>A+</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="index">2</td><td>1952</td><td>Ciclano da Silva</td><td>B</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="index">3</td><td>1963</td><td>Beltrano Pereira</td><td>A+</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="index">4</td><td>1973</td><td>Joãozinho Mendes</td><td>C</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="index">5</td><td>1965</td><td>José Ciclano</td><td>A</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

E estou utilizando o seguinte código para "sortear" os valores:

```
var fixHelperModified = function(e, tr) {
    var $originals = tr.children();
    var $helper = tr.clone();
    $helper.children().each(function(index) {
        $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width())
    });
                console.log(tr.clone());
    return $helper;

},
    updateIndex = function(e, ui) {
        $('td.index', ui.item.parent()).each(function (i) {
            $(this).html(i + 1);
            console.log($(this).html(i + 1).val);
        });
    };

$("#sort tbody").sortable({
    helper: fixHelperModified,
    stop: updateIndex
}).disableSelection();
```

Em meu código, eu preciso criar uma variável para salvar os valores das posições (inicial e final).

Possuo um exemplo funcional no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qpbrqrqe/). Basta "arrastar e soltar" a linha, para entender melhor o que tentei explicar.

Answer (score 1):

Veja esse exemplo no [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Wfsc6/)

Encontrei aqui [StackOverFlow -  Sortable Change event element position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956039/jquery-sortable-change-event-element-position)

coloquei um `console.log(pos);` 
que te mostra o retorno com começo e o final de cada movimento.

```js
var comeco,final;
$( "#sortable" ).sortable({
    change: function(event, ui) {  
        var pos = ui.helper.index() > ui.placeholder.index() 
            ? { start: ui.helper.index(), end: ui.placeholder.index() }
            : { start: ui.placeholder.index(), end: ui.helper.index() }
       comeco = pos.start;  
        final = pos.end; 
         ui.item.startPos = ui.item.index();
        $(this)
            .children().removeClass( 'highlight' )
            .not( ui.helper ).slice( pos.start, pos.end ).addClass( 'highlight' );
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).children().removeClass( 'highlight' );
        console.log("nova: " + ui.item.index());
        console.log("inicial: " + ui.item.startPos);
    }
});
```

```css
#sortable { 
    list-style-type: none; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    width: 60%; 
}
.ui-state-default { 
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    background-color: #E4E4E4;
    margin: 0 3px 3px 3px; 
    padding: 0.4em;
    font-size: 1.4em; 
    height: 18px; 
}
.highlight{
    background-color: #B24926; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<ul id="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 6</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 7</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 8</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 9</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Seria quase isso. Porém, se você observar, ao arrastar para baixo, o **start** que e a posição inicial, mas se arrastar para cima, o **end** que é a posição inicial. Eu preciso que fique fixo, independente da posição que arrastar. Pois esses valores serão levados para um método e alterado no banco de dados.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Wfsc6/80/

Comment: Eu cheguei a fazer isso @GabrielRodrigues. Porém, arraste o item 1 para o item 2 e depois retorne para a posição original. Você verá que os valores serão os mesmos. A variável `começo` sempre está ficando com o valor menor. Porém, se eu arrastar um item de baixo para cima, ela teria que ficar com um valor maior.

Comment: entendi, o seu objetivo final seria ? deixar no banco como essa grade esta configurada ?

Comment: A demanda seria atualizar a sequencia no banco também. Eu usei seu código como base, e fiz essas alterações, se quiser completar seu código, eu marco como correta, pois ajudou muito sua resposta. http://jsfiddle.net/Wfsc6/83/
E se possível, traga o código para a resposta, pois o link pode não existir com o tempo.

Comment: Eu achei que estava certo, mas não está também não... rsrs.
De baixo para cima, está funcionando normal. Porém, de cima para baixo está com um valor, mas se alterar os mesmos itens de baixo para cima, os valores ficam diferentes.